# How can i insert a information_schema inside a stored proceedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

guys im quite new to stored proceedures. can anyone guide me on how to put the following simple sql query inside a stored proceedure

```
$tables = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Fogdb' AND table_name LIKE 'fdb_table_%' ");
```

i tried like below but it dint work

DELIMITER $$

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `alter_test_1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`Fogdb`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `alter_test_1`()
BEGIN

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Fogdb' AND table_name LIKE 'fdb_table_%' 

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How didn't it work? Please provide any error or describe how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
create procedure test()
begin
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Fogdb' AND table_name LIKE 'fdb_table_%'; 
end
```

In your script, You have forget to put ';' at end of query;

Now try

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `alter_test_1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`adtracker`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `alter_test_1`()
BEGIN

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Fogdb' AND table_name LIKE 'fdb_table_%' ;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```